# How do i write this without using ALL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Write a query to find only those customers whose grade are, higher than every customer to the city New York

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE grade > ALL
   (SELECT grade
    FROM customer
    WHERE city='New York');
```

Comment: This looks like homework.

Comment: A few people already posted a possible solution. I just want to add that using a sub-query like that, although functional, implies in major performance loss in most scenarios. MySQL does not optimize that well at all. This kind of solution should be avoided if you can help it, and use a `JOIN` instead.

Comment: @Nick thanks for the heads up i had no idea. Will rectify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`MAX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) in your subquery instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE grade > 
   (SELECT MAX(grade)
    FROM customer
    WHERE city='New York');
```

As @GordonLinoff points out, if there are no customers from `New York`, this query will fail. You can work around that by using `COALESCE` to convert the `MAX` value from `NULL` to `-1` (basically you need a number which is lower than the lowest possible value of `grade`) e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE grade > 
   (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(grade), -1)
    FROM customer
    WHERE city='New York');
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=713ca2594d6a513581635fbcb663307c)

Comment: @NeverQuit101 . . . This answer is not correct.  Read my explanation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is correct; I've edited the answer so it will work in that situation. See the demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [max()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max):

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE grade > (SELECT max(grade) FROM customer WHERE city='New York')
```

Note that this won't select any customers from 'New York', only for other cities.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`max`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) instead. If `grade` and `city` are  indexed together this will be very fast.

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE grade > (
  SELECT max(grade)
  FROM customer
  WHERE city='New York'
);
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=614c02808e3da66e5d7cabe70ce26d60)

Answer (score 1):

You have to be very careful with this.  It is tempting to write:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer c
WHERE grade > (SELECT MAX(c2.grade)
               FROM customer c2
               WHERE c2.city = 'New York'
              );
```

However, this returns no rows if no customers are in New York.  But the `ALL` version -- and the statement of the problem -- suggest that *all* customers should be returned.

The simplest solution is a `COALESCE()`, such as:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customer c
WHERE grade > (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(c2.grade), c.grade - 1)
               FROM customer c2
               WHERE c2.city = 'New York'
              );
```

Alternatively, you can use window functions:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             max(case when c.city = 'New York' then c.grade end) as ny_grade
      from customer c
     ) c
where grade > ny_grade or ny_grade is null;
```